# Spring Data - Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data

Am very new to Spring Data + Spring Boot. I have downloaded Spring Data project and am trying to configuring in my Eclipse.

While am executing the project am getting the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
```

Please find my Application.java file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private ElasticsearchOperations es;

@Autowired
private BookService bookService;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    printElasticSearchInfo();

    bookService.save(new Book("1001", "Elasticsearch Basics", "Rambabu Posa", "23-FEB-2017"));
    bookService.save(new Book("1002", "Apache Lucene Basics", "Rambabu Posa", "13-MAR-2017"));
    bookService.save(new Book("1003", "Apache Solr Basics", "Rambabu Posa", "21-MAR-2017"));

    //fuzzey search
    Page<Book> books = bookService.findByAuthor("Rambabu", new PageRequest(0, 10));

    //List<Book> books = bookService.findByTitle("Elasticsearch Basics");

    books.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));


}

//useful for debug
private void printElasticSearchInfo() {

    System.out.println("--ElasticSearch-->");
    Client client = es.getClient();
    Map<String, String> asMap = client.settings().getAsMap();

    asMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println(k + " = " + v);
    });
    System.out.println("<--ElasticSearch--");
}

}
```

**Update 1 **

```
--ElasticSearch-->
client.type = transport
cluster.name = mkyong-cluster
name = Hyde
network.server = false
node.client = true
transport.ping_schedule = 5s
<--ElasticSearch--
2018-10-09 13:30:56.797  INFO 11476 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-09 13:30:56.842 ERROR 11476 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.mkyong.Application.main(Application.java:26) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:223) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:295) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:359) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:56) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.index(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:536) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.save(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:142) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mkyong.book.service.BookServiceImpl.save(BookServiceImpl.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mkyong.Application.run(Application.java:34) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Please find my application.properties file

```
elasticsearch.clustername = mkyong-cluster
elasticsearch.host = localhost
elasticsearch.port = 9300
```

**Update 2**

```
2018-10-09 14:34:01.155  INFO 12400 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Terminatrix] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9200}, disconnecting...

org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9200][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [0] timed out after [5037ms]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:698) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

2018-10-09 14:34:01.455 ERROR 12400 --- [           main] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9200}]
2018-10-09 14:34:01.789  INFO 12400 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
```

Also, i have installed ElasticSearch 6.2.3 (which is latest version). But in stacktrace it showing `elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4`. How can i reconfigure it.?

Comment: You're also getting a comprehensive stack trace under that single line, which you should post.

Comment: @chrylis - I have updated the stacktrace

Comment: could you post elastric search config properties ?

Comment: @BooBerr'ita - I have updated my `application.properties` file details also.

Comment: The issue is that elastic search is not reachable. Are you running elastic search locally on port 9300?

Comment: @GerbenJongerius - You are correct, its due to the port issue i have changed to `9200`. But now am receiving `timedout` error. I have updated the stacktrace for the same.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Spring-data-elastic-search is not supporting ES 6.2. as you can see in your stack trace, your ES version is 2.4.

If you want to use 6.2, you need to use HignLevelRestClient (a Java-based API for ES)

Here is the configuration for ES 6.2

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractFactoryBean {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes}")
    private String clusterNodes;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name}")
    private String clusterName;
    private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            if (restHighLevelClient != null) {
                restHighLevelClient.close();
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error closing ElasticSearch client: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<RestHighLevelClient> getObjectType() {
        return RestHighLevelClient.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient createInstance() {
        return buildClient();
    }

    private RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
        try {
            restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return restHighLevelClient;
    }

}
```

And here is your Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Map<String, Object> getBookById(@PathVariable String id){
      return bookRepository.getBookById(id);
    }
```

Here is your Repository:

```
@Repository
public class BookRepository {

    private final String INDEX = "bookdata";
      private final String TYPE = "books";  
      private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;
      private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

      public BookRepository( ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
      }

      public Map<String, Object> getBookById(String id){
          GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(INDEX, TYPE, id);
          GetResponse getResponse = null;
          try {
            getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest);
          } catch (java.io.IOException e){
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
          }
          Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = getResponse.getSourceAsMap();
          return sourceAsMap;
        }
```

Here is your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ElasticsearchImplApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ElasticsearchImplApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And here is your Config file:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=your-cluster
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=elasticsearch
```

I hope this will help.